# Why use keras as backend instead of using tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I see that there are many similar functions between tensorflow and keras like argmax, boolean_mask...I wonder why people have to use keras as backend along with tensorflow instead of using tensorflow alone.

Comment: Keras is not a backend it uses tensorflow or theano as  backend. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/ 

Keras is used as it provides some high lever APIs to tensorflow features

Comment: As stated by @sarthakupadhyay Tensorflow can be used as a backend for Keras. Keras is what we call a high-level API. That means that Keras makes/should make our life easier when using low-level APIs such as Tensorflow or Theano

Answer (score 1):

Keras is not a backend, but it is a high-level API for building and training Neural Networks. Keras is capable of running on top of Tensorflow, Theano and CNTK. Most of the people prefer Keras due to its simplicity compared to other libraries like Tensorflow. I recommend Keras for beginners in Deep Learning.

Answer (score 0):

> A Keras tensor is a tensor object from the underlying backend (Theano,
>   TensorFlow or CNTK), which we augment with certain attributes that
>   allow us to build a Keras model just by knowing the inputs and outputs
>   of the model.

**Theano vs Tensorflow**

Tensorflow is necessary if you wish to use coremltools. Apple has promised support for architectures created using Theano but I haven't seen it yet.

Keras will require unique syntax sugar depending on the backend in use. I like the flexibility of Tensorflow input layers and easy-access to strong Google neural networks.